# Problem with netCDF Fortran compilation: C compiler doesn't work

Tags: c, gcc, configuration, netcdf, openmpi

I have a problem with netCDF Fortran compilation. Here is the output of my compilation:

```
configure: netCDF-Fortran 4.5.3 
checking build system type... x86_64-pc-linux-gnu 
checking host system type... x86_64-pc-linux-gnu 
checking target system type... x86_64-pc-linux-gnu 
checking for a BSD-compatible install... /usr/bin/install -c 
checking whether build environment is sane... yes 
checking for a thread-safe mkdir -p... /usr/bin/mkdir -p 
checking for gawk... no 
checking for mawk... mawk
checking whether make sets $(MAKE)... yes 
checking whether make supports nested variables... yes 
checking whether to enable maintainer-specific portions of Makefiles... no 
configure: checking user options 
checking whether make supports the include directive... yes (GNU style) 
checking for gcc... /home/ksenia/prgs4mom/openmpi_4.1.1/bin/mpicc 
checking whether the C compiler works... no
configure: error: in `/home/ksenia/prgs4mom/src/netcdf-fortran-4.5.3': 
configure: error: C compiler cannot create executables 
See config.log for more details 
make: *** No targets specified and no makefile found.  Stop.
```

Here is my compilation script:

```
#!/bin/bash
export CC="/home/ksenia/prgs4mom/openmpi_4.1.1/bin/mpicc"
export FC="/home/ksenia/prgs4mom/openmpi_4.1.1/bin/mpif90"
export F77="/home/ksenia/prgs4mom/openmpi_4.1.1/bin/mpifort"
export CXX="/home/ksenia/prgs4mom/openmpi_4.1.1/bin/mpicxx"

export CPPFLAGS="$(echo "nc-config --cflags")"
export LDFLAGS="$(echo "nc-config --libs")"
export LIBS="-lnetcdf"

export CFLAGS="-DgFortran"
export CPPLAGS="-DgFortran"
export CXXFLAGS="-DgFortran"

./configure --disable-shared --prefix=/home/ksenia/prgs4mom/netcdf_fortran_4.5.3

make && sudo make install
```

It also should be noted that if I comment the strings providing LDFLAGS, CPPFLAGS and LIBS, compilation will go another understandable way (I cut the output for more convenient view):

```
configure: netCDF-Fortran 4.5.3 
checking build system type... x86_64-pc-linux-gnu 
checking host system type... x86_64-pc-linux-gnu 
checking target system type... x86_64-pc-linux-gnu
checking for a BSD-compatible install... /usr/bin/install -c
checking whether build environment is sane... yes
checking for a thread-safe mkdir -p... /usr/bin/mkdir -p
checking for gawk... no
checking for mawk... mawk
checking whether make sets $(MAKE)... yes
checking whether make supports nested variables... yes
checking whether to enable maintainer-specific portions of Makefiles... no
configure: checking user options
checking whether make supports the include directive... yes (GNU style)
checking for gcc... /home/ksenia/prgs4mom/openmpi_4.1.1/bin/mpicc
checking whether the C compiler works... yes
checking for C compiler default output file name... a.out
***
configure: error: netcdf-c version 4.7.4 or greater is required 
make: *** No targets specified and no makefile found.  Stop.
```

Here is the output of `nc-config --all`:

```
This netCDF 4.7.4 has been built with the following features: 

  --cc            -> /home/ksenia/prgs4mom/openmpi_4.1.1/bin/mpicc
  --cflags        -> -I/home/ksenia/prgs4mom/netcdf_c_4.7.4/include -I/home/ksenia/prgs4mom/zlib_1.2.11/include -I/home/ksenia/prgs4mom/curl_7.77.0/include -I/usr/lib/gcc/x86_64-linux-gnu/9/include -I/usr/include -I/home/ksenia/prgs4mom/openmpi_4.1.1/include -I/home/ksenia/prgs4mom/hdf5_1.12.0/include -I/home/ksenia/prgs4mom/pnetcdf_1.12.2/include
  --libs          -> -L/home/ksenia/prgs4mom/netcdf_c_4.7.4/lib -L/home/ksenia/prgs4mom/zlib_1.2.11/lib -L/home/ksenia/prgs4mom/curl_7.77.0/lib -L/usr/lib -L/usr/lib/gcc/x86_64-linux-gnu/9 -L/home/ksenia/prgs4mom/openmpi_4.1.1/lib -L/home/ksenia/prgs4mom/hdf5_1.12.0/lib -L/home/ksenia/prgs4mom/pnetcdf_1.12.2/lib -lnetcdf -lpnetcdf -lhdf5_hl -lhdf5 -lm -ldl -lz -lcurl 
  --static        -> -lpnetcdf -lhdf5_hl -lhdf5 -lm -ldl -lz -lcurl 

  --has-c++       -> no
  --cxx           -> 

  --has-c++4      -> no
  --cxx4          -> 

  --has-fortran   -> no
  --has-dap       -> yes
  --has-dap2      -> yes
  --has-dap4      -> yes
  --has-nc2       -> yes
  --has-nc4       -> yes
  --has-hdf5      -> yes
  --has-hdf4      -> no
  --has-logging   -> no
  --has-pnetcdf   -> yes
  --has-szlib     -> no
  --has-cdf5      -> yes
  --has-parallel4 -> yes
  --has-parallel  -> yes

  --prefix        -> /home/ksenia/prgs4mom/netcdf_c_4.7.4
  --includedir    -> /home/ksenia/prgs4mom/netcdf_c_4.7.4/include
  --libdir        -> /home/ksenia/prgs4mom/netcdf_c_4.7.4/lib
  --version       -> netCDF 4.7.4
```

Can someone please explain me what I've done wrong and why configure recap there is no working C compilers on my PC if I provide an information about netCDF-C and how to fix it? 

Thank you!

Answer (score 0):

I had the same problem while trying to install WRF and netCDF on my Macbook Pro running Ventura. In one of the installation shell script, it insisted that the script be run as superuser. So I did this

> > sudo ./configure

and the compilation went past this problem of C compiler issue. There are other related problems with path setting etc, one needs to take care of.

- Vidyadhar Mudkavi
  2023-08-19